# Passing binary data from Python to C API extension

Tags: python, c, api

I'm writing a Python (**2.6**) extension, and I have a situation where I need to pass an opaque binary blob (with embedded null bytes) to my extension.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
from authbind import authenticate

creds = 'foo\x00bar\x00'
authenticate(creds)
```

which throws the following:

```
TypeError: argument 1 must be string without null bytes, not str
```

Here is some of authbind.cc:

```
static PyObject* authenticate(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {

    const char* creds;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &creds))
        return NULL;
}
```

So far, I have tried passing the blob as a raw string, like `creds = '%r' % creds`, but that not only gives me embedded quotes around the string but also turns the `\x00` bytes into their literal string representations, which I do not want to mess around with in C.

How can I accomplish what I need? I know about the `y`, `y#` and `y*` PyArg_ParseTuple() format characters in 3.2, but I am limited to 2.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a with the help of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955250/python-c-api-unicode-arguments?rq=1).

I used a `PyByteArrayObject` (docs [here](http://docs.python.org/2.6/c-api/bytearray.html)) like this:

```
from authbind import authenticate

creds = 'foo\x00bar\x00'
authenticate(bytearray(creds))
```

And then in the extension code:

```
static PyObject* authenticate(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {

    PyByteArrayObject *creds;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &creds))
        return NULL;

    char* credsCopy;
    credsCopy = PyByteArray_AsString((PyObject*) creds);
}
```

`credsCopy` now holds the string of bytes, exactly as they are needed.

Comment: You can use `"s#"`, with a `Py_ssize_t` for the length: [Parsing arguments and building values](http://docs.python.org/2.6/c-api/arg.html).

Comment: @eryksun: Yes, you're right! I must have missed that. Your solution would also work, Thanks!